# Is there a way to send JavaScript queries with python without a (headless) browser?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I want to extract data from a website that uses hicharts within its login area.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

I would like to do it without the use of selenium or phantomJS, which both would be overkill but I´m not sure how.
In selenium my code would look like this:

```
data = driver.execute_script('''
values = [];
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data.forEach((d) => values.push(d.y));
return values;
''')
```

If you want to test this in your browsers console use:

```
values = [];Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data.forEach(function(d){ values.push(d.y) });console.log(values);
```

As I understand requests_html has JS support but I was not able to make any progress.

```
c=session.html.render(script='''values = [];
     Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data.forEach((d) => values.push(d.y));
     return values;''')
```

This gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'HTMLSession' object has no attribute 'html'
```

Is there another way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Search for `beautifulsoup` for webscraping using python

Comment: I´m using bs4 but I´m not sure how or even if I could extract the graphs data with it. The scrapable html data doesn´t make much sense if you check the source code

Comment: You could try one of [these](https://scrapingant.com/blog/top-5-popular-javascript-libraries-for-web-scraping-in-2020) javascript scraping options?

Comment: well I´m aware that i can do this with node.js but my question was if it is possible with python

Comment: As far as I know there is no way of doing that. There are libraries that allow you to execute javascript in python but that will not give you a satisfying result here. Also please note that ''requests_html'' has not been updated for a while and can be considered discontinued.